# Remove text from excel columns with certain criteria

Tags: excel

I have some excel rows and some of them contain two names, but I want to completely get rid of the second name if it exists. E.g.

```
Tom Jones                           ok
Michael Jones and Helen Smith       not ok
Michael Bloggs and Gemma Jones      not ok
John Murphy and Hannah Murphy       not ok
Jane Brown                          ok
```

Is there a formula to get rid of the second name if the column (if they have a second name)?

Anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If having `and` means there's going to be a second name, you can put this in a new column (say C1), and drag down. It'll return only the first name:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" and ",A1)),A1)`

Note this will allow you to have a name, such as `Randy Jones` and it won't cut it out, but it'll keep `Randy Jones` from the names `Randy Jones and Mary Poppins`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a find formula such as:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(" and ",A1,1)-1),A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("and ",A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `LEFT` and `FIND` into a helper column:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" and",A1)-1)
```

Then copy and paste values over your old data.